# How would I align an image to the bottom right of the view using Size Classes in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, autolayout, size-classes

I have an image that I want to align with the bottom right corner of the View and then I want the rest of the image to scale to fill the available space but without falling off screen.

My image is a square, so I don't want the width of the image to be any greater than the device's shortest side (portrait or landscape).

I'm new to Size Classes, but no matter what constraints I apply, the image grows bigger than the view and seems to have a gap between the bottom and right had edges of the screen, even though I've set those constraints to 0.

Comment: regarding the gap: check that you ignore the margins - can be set by double clicking the constraint

Answer (score 0):

Your specifications are a little unclear, which may account for the difficulty you're having; you need to be very clear on exactly what you want. I had no trouble making a square image be square and fill the shorter dimension exactly in both orientations:

[image]

[image]

So if that's what you want, it's easily achieved with constraints (no size classes involved).

Comment: minor detail: he wanted bottom right ;) not bottom left

Comment: @luk2302 I was never very good at right vs. left. But hey, if it fills the whole bottom how can you tell which is which? :) Anyway, let's see if this is even what he means; I couldn't make much sense of what he was saying.

Comment: @matt sorry I knew I'd have trouble explaining what I wanted, but you've more or less got it. Which constraints would I need to set to do what you've achieved? It needs to be exactly bottom right as the graphic is designed to fit in to a corner (it's a bit like a callout).  The reason I mentioned size classes is that I'm using them in my storyboard, and applying this effort to the Anyw x Anyh 'size' if that makes sense? Not sure whether this matters but thought I'd add it in

Comment: But if it is really a square of maximum size, it is not bottom right - it's just bottom (in portrait) or right (in landscape). Is that correct?